No result in transcription while using AWS Transcribe Streaming Service
I am trying to implement a transcription function inside a Nextjs app. The function is terminated fast with empty string without waiting for the stream to end.
export const get_aws = async (file: File, code: string) => {
  async function* getAudioStream(file: File) {
    const audioStream = file.stream();
    const reader = audioStream.getReader();
    try {
      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;
        yield { AudioEvent: { AudioChunk: value } };
      }
    } finally {
      reader.releaseLock();
    }
  }
  const transcribe_client = new TranscribeStreamingClient({
    region: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_REGION as string,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID as string,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as string,
    },
  });
  const params = {
    TranscriptionJobName: file.name,
    LanguageCode: code as LanguageCode,
    MediaEncoding: MediaEncoding.OGG_OPUS,
    MediaSampleRateHertz: 48000,
    AudioStream: getAudioStream(file),
  };
  let transcription = "";
  try {
    const response = await transcribe_client.send(
      new StartStreamTranscriptionCommand(params),
    );
    for await (const event of response?.TranscriptResultStream as any) {
      if (event.TranscriptEvent) {
        transcription +=
          event.TranscriptEvent.Transcript.Results[0].Alternatives[0]
            .Transcript;
      }
    }
    return transcription.trim();
  } catch (error) {
    throw `Error Fetching AWS: ${error}`;
  }
};

I tried calling it from a async function in the frontend and storing the result in a state variable. Result is always empty string.
